# why node class 'selected' disappeared after brushend in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have nodes and edges in force layout using d3. Now I want to brush some nodes and add class "selected" to nodes which are brushed. It works fine in the brush process, but once brush ended, the class "selected" disappeared, I don't know why. Here's my code:

```
  function brushstarted () {
    console.log('brush start')
    nodegroup.each(function (d) {
      d.selected = false
      d.previouslySelected = false
    })
  }

  function brushed () {
    let selection = d3.event.selection
    nodegroup.classed('selected', function (d) {
      d.selected = d.previouslySelected ^ (selection != null && selection[0][0] <= d.x && d.x < selection[1][0] && selection[0][1] <= d.y && d.y < selection[1][1])
      return d.selected
    })
  }

  function brushended () {
    console.log('brush end')
    if (d3.event.selection !== null) {
      d3.select(this).call(d3.event.target.move, null)
    }
  }
```

Here are nodes in "brushed" state and "brushended" state, as you can see, at the "brushended" state, the node should be as same as "brushed", but it doesn't, that's my question, how can I solve it? [nodes in "brushed" state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKW7q.jpg)  [nodes in "brushend" state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWgbc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. Just add a line of code in brushed function

```
if (d3.event.sourceEvent.type !== 'end') {
    // previous code move into here
}
```